# Unable to refresh question list on the new Stack Overflow app

Tags: bug, ios-app, question-lists

When you're at the top of the question list using the iOS Stack Exchange app you can pull the list down to refresh it:

[image]

This however is not available on the new Stack Overflow app:

[image]

The current way to refresh is to click the sort, in this case *Active* and then click the sort again which will refresh the list. This is just a bit clumsy in my opinion and a pull down refresh is much better.

Note, this only seems to be a problem when I've filtered the question list using a tag say. If no search is performed and all questions are viewed then the refreshing works by pulling the list down.

Can it please be fixed?

Comment: For what it's worth, the behavior is consistent across the two apps.  The first screenshot shows a filtered sort and the second screenshot shows a search (cancel button is visible).  I'm honestly not sure why refresh was never incorporated into search but I'll look at what it'll take to add it.

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel I did try and replicate so it was the same but obviously got that wrong :)